# how can I delay perform Segue with identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, swift5

I have RouteVC and I'm controlling Auth from it.. either to swich the user to the AppVC or divert him to Auth page.

During performing the movement between the App & Auth apges I want somedelay to display some animation or a msg inside RouteVC

So can you help me how to do the delay between ViewControllers?

```
class Route: UIViewController{

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        if user == nil {
            // User Signed out
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Auth", sender: nil)
        } else {
            // User Signed In
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "App", sender: nil)

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `asyncAfter` method of `DispatchQueue` to delay calling any code. Whatever that is inside the closure/block will get executed after the delay you specify, in the below case I've set it to 2 seconds from the current time.

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
    // Place your code to execute after a delay of 2 seconds here.
    // Before calling `asyncAfter` perform showing loader or anything you want.
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.... thank you very much for your prompt response as usuall

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted @badhanganesh's answer but wanted to mention that `UIView.animate` has a completion block. You can use completion blocks to execute code after something is done, rather than running a 2-second animation and a 2-second asyncAfter delay (which is not reliable).

```
// run a 0.5 second animation
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
    // your animations
}, completion: { _ in
    // show your view controller once the animation is completed

    // if you want to further delay, use asyncAfter
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        // code excutes after 2 seconds
    }
})
```

Likewise, you can create a completion handler for your custom function that handles showing an animation or message.

Comment: The animation will be implemented from the storyboard, so for me  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter is enogh for my code.... thank you for your help